# When spark serializer is used with Dataframe API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm wondering when `spark.serializer` is used if my application uses  `DataFrame` API ?

If I understand well :

- Not for caching or shuffling.
- Only for closure serialization and broadcast variable.

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

***spark.serializer*** has its use when working with **RDDs**, and is used for shuffling data between worker,checkpointing ,serializing **RDDs** to disk etc.

**DataFrame** has it's own columnar storage for caching. Hence **spark.serializer** has no impact at all.

Spark uses ***spark.closure.serializer***  is used to for serialization of closure and broadcast variable, which is a JavaSerializer.

To answer your points

1. Yes. Since Dataframe uses it's own columnar storage for caching. Hence **spark.serializer** has no impact.
2. No. For closure and broadcast variable serialization **closureSerializer** under **spark.closure.serializer** is used, which is a **JavaSerializer** .